# CRUD Repository not storing files from mySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

Attempting to create a simple site that displays the content on my MySql database. I use the word attempting loosely lol. Notice the pages I have "/all" which I use to check if my list is empty. I'm trying to figure out why is my list empty and not storing the content of my database?

MySql:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `web_customer_tracker`;
USE `web_customer_tracker`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `customer`;
CREATE TABLE `customer`(
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`first_name` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`last_name` VARCHAR(45)DEFAULT NULL,
`email` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `customer` VALUES
    (1, 'David', 'Adams', 'david@luv2code.com'),
    (2, 'John', 'Die', 'john@luv2code.com'),
    (3, 'Ajay', 'Rao', 'ajay@luv2code.com'),
    (4, 'Mary', 'Publiidc', 'mary@luv2code.com'),
    (5, 'Maxwell', 'Dixon', 'maxwell@luv2code.com');
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "id")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    public Customer(){}

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String company){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = company;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getCompany() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setCompany(String company) {
        this.email = company;
    }
}
```

DAO

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface CustomerDAO extends CrudRepository<Customer, String> {
    public List<Customer> findAll();

}
```

Impl:

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public abstract class CustomerDAOImpl implements CustomerDAO {



    private CustomerDAO customerDAO;

    @Override
    public List<Customer> findAll() {

       return customerDAO.findAll();

        }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerDAO customerDAO;
    public String string;



    @RequestMapping(value = "/list")
    public String listCustomers(Model model){
    List<Customer> customers = customerDAO.findAll();
    String string = customers.get(1).toString();

    model.addAttribute("text", string);
    model.addAttribute("customers", customers);
    return "list-customers";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/all")
    @ResponseBody
    public String get() {


        List<Customer> customers = customerDAO.findAll();
        String names;

        if(customers.isEmpty() == true){
            names = "This is empty";
        } else {
            names = "Something is in here";
        }


        return names;
    }
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7536 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/ronald/IdeaProjects/springtutorial/target/classes:/Users/ronald/mysql-connector-java-5.1.41/mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.9/logback-classic-1.1.9.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.9/logback-core-1.1.9.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.22/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.22.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.22/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.17/snakeyaml-1.17.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring4/2.1.5.RELEASE/thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/nz/net/ultraq/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/1.4.0/thymeleaf-layout-dialect-1.4.0.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.4.7/groovy-2.4.7.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.5.11/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.3.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.8.6/jackson-databind-2.8.6.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.8.0/jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.8.6/jackson-core-2.8.6.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.2.9.Final/hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.21.0-GA/javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec/1.0.1.Final/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.0.3.Final/jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.3.3/classmate-1.3.3.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.0.1.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.40/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/c3p0/c3p0/0.9.1.2/c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.9/aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.5.11/tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.5.11/tomcat-juli-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/5.0.11.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.11.0.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.13.0.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.22/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring3/3.0.3.RELEASE/thymeleaf-spring3-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/2.1.5.RELEASE/thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/unbescape/unbescape/1.1.0.RELEASE/unbescape-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.22/slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.5.11/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.5.11/tomcat-embed-el-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.luv2code.springtutorial.Application

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.1.RELEASE)

2017-04-16 20:11:51.726  INFO 8023 --- [           main] com.luv2code.springtutorial.Application  : Starting Application on Ronalds-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 8023 (/Users/ronald/IdeaProjects/springtutorial/target/classes started by ronald in /Users/ronald/IdeaProjects/springtutorial)
2017-04-16 20:11:51.729  INFO 8023 --- [           main] com.luv2code.springtutorial.Application  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-04-16 20:11:52.009  INFO 8023 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4f9a3314: startup date [Sun Apr 16 20:11:52 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-04-16 20:11:53.416  INFO 8023 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-04-16 20:11:53.517  INFO 8023 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'validator' of type [class org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-04-16 20:11:53.579  INFO 8023 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$84f7773b] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-04-16 20:11:54.026  INFO 8023 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-04-16 20:11:54.050  INFO 8023 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-04-16 20:11:54.051  INFO 8023 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
2017-04-16 20:11:54.217  INFO 8023 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-04-16 20:11:54.218  INFO 8023 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2212 ms
2017-04-16 20:11:54.424  INFO 8023 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-04-16 20:11:54.431  INFO 8023 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-16 20:11:54.432  INFO 8023 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-16 20:11:54.432  INFO 8023 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-16 20:11:54.432  INFO 8023 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-16 20:11:55.310  INFO 8023 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-04-16 20:11:55.339  INFO 8023 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-04-16 20:11:55.420  INFO 8023 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.9.Final}
2017-04-16 20:11:55.422  INFO 8023 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-04-16 20:11:55.607  INFO 8023 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-04-16 20:11:55.739  INFO 8023 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2017-04-16 20:11:56.398  INFO 8023 --- [           main] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@1e225820'
2017-04-16 20:11:56.403  INFO 8023 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-04-16 20:11:57.156  INFO 8023 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4f9a3314: startup date [Sun Apr 16 20:11:52 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-04-16 20:11:57.276  INFO 8023 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/all]}" onto public java.lang.String com.luv2code.springtutorial.controller.CustomerController.get()
2017-04-16 20:11:57.278  INFO 8023 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/list]}" onto public java.lang.String com.luv2code.springtutorial.controller.CustomerController.listCustomers(org.springframework.ui.Model)
2017-04-16 20:11:57.283  INFO 8023 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-04-16 20:11:57.284  INFO 8023 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-04-16 20:11:57.342  INFO 8023 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-04-16 20:11:57.342  INFO 8023 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-04-16 20:11:57.425  INFO 8023 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-04-16 20:11:58.236  INFO 8023 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-04-16 20:11:58.335  INFO 8023 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-04-16 20:11:58.342  INFO 8023 --- [           main] com.luv2code.springtutorial.Application  : Started Application in 17.231 seconds (JVM running for 17.958)
2017-04-16 20:12:03.155  INFO 8023 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-04-16 20:12:03.155  INFO 8023 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-04-16 20:12:03.176  INFO 8023 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 21 ms
2017-04-16 20:12:04.403  INFO 8023 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to figure out why is my list empty and not storing the content of my database

Comment: suppose that your model class `@id` is type `int` the crudrepository should be `CrudRepository<Customer, int>` this [post](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-two-crud/) may be helpful

Comment: Tried changing it to type Integer and still seems to be empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first ,

Make sure you have done the below things.

1. You do not need CustomerDAOImpl, remove it.
2. In CustomerDAO change `<Customer,String>` to `<Customer,Integer>`
3. Again in the same interface remove `@Transactional` and `@Repository`, they are not required.

Rest of the code looks just fine. Try the above steps.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

suppose you remove the `CustomerDAOImpl` class and see.

You only need the Entity class (`Customer`) , Repository interface (`CustomerDAO`) which extends`CrudRepository<Customer, int>` and the controller.

Comment: share the exception you are getting.

Comment: added my stack trace but not getting any noticeable error

Comment: did you check the `/list` or `/all` urls whether there is a exception.

Comment: Both pages load up correctly, doesn't seem to be an exception

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, if i am not wrong then where is your entitymanager and other database operation to fetch the list(). I mean where is the logic to fetch data.
your `return customerDAO.findAll();` did nothing at all.you just calling method and no other things actually.